# DHCP Server Authorized But Won't Work

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, windows-server-2019

I have 2 DHCP servers that I have had to replace. On I unauthorized the old servers and when I go to authorize the new servers, it is added to the authorized list but the IPV4/IPV6 areas still show not authorized. It looks like this:

[image]

I have restarted the DHCP, DNS, and NETLOGON service and still nothing. What am I doing wrong? I have checked AD Sites & Services > Services > NetServices and servers show up in there as well. Still the new DHCP servers do not show as authorized? How do I get them authorized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching through authorizers I went to the main DHCP server and checked the services to ensure the addresses are in NetServices Attributes. I then restarted that server and when it came back on I restarted the 2 new DHCP servers and the authorized servers started working again. Something was hung up about authorization on the main DHCP server.

Comment: This fixed my issue also. DHCP appeared authorized in AD and even "netsh dhcp show server" showed the correct new servers. I had to reboot the old server to compete the unauthorizing and even the new ones after that.